# JavaScript change div class on text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change the `<div>` class if the text more than 0. My code is:

```
$(function () {
    if (parseInt($(".notification-counter").text()) == 0) {
        //$(".notification-counter").hide();
        $(".notification-container").hide();
    }
});
```

But this code will just hide the `<div>` if text is equal to 0. Instead, I need to change the `<div>` if the text is more than 0. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add/remove a class to that `div`?

Comment: change the hide to an addclass or toggleClass('whateverclassyouwant') then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you specified you want to change the class when the text is "more than 0", you can change your conditional to *greater than zero* like so..

```
if(parseInt($(".notification-counter").text()) > 0)
```

Then you can add a class like so...

```
$('.notification-container').addClass('newClass');
```

If you would first like to check for another class for possible removal, you can create an if statement using jQuery's [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) then use removeClass() and addClass() accordingly.

Here's an example that adds `.new-class` to the container when the value is above 0 http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwXZMq

Comment: your add class should not have a period before the class name.
`$('.notification-container').addClass('notification-container2');`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are wanting the [`.length`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp) property. Try the following...

```
$(function () {
    if ($(".notification-counter").text().length === 0) {
        $(".notification-container").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You use Jquery, so you have many possibilities to do that, look at their [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) you have the [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) function, the [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) function and the [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) function that allow you many things.

And for the easier solution :

```
$(function () {
if (parseInt($(".notification-counter").text()) != 0) {
    $(".notification-container").addClass("myclass");
}
});
```

EDIT : `if (parseInt($(".notification-counter").text()) != 0)`

Comment: so did are you an answer or a rater ?

Comment: ok, so go play elsewhere. Read his first words "I need to CHANGE DIV CLASS if the text more than 0"

Comment: look at the comments below the question, you will see that I'm not the only one who understanding the things like that. Sorry man, english isn't my maternal language, like you as I see "@Michael0x2a: If you are going to fix grammar, I suggest you learn it yourself first"

Comment: People dont be angry... Why does it not working? http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/783h57zy/

Comment: Erick what are you looking for ? Are you looking for the value of the text ou the length (in pixel) ?

Comment: @Antoine Pointeau i'm looking for value. sorry my english is bad... what i need todo: if text in div are more than 0 the div class color is #6FB205 but if div text less than 1 the div class color changed to #FF7C30